# line on the minimal value not visible

Tags: highcharts

If I set the minimum value (min:0 yAxis), and the line is crossing is the minimum value, then part of the line is not visible. How to fix this? I want to line is at the minimum value was visible.

[http://jsfiddle.net/NQyQ6/][1]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is known bug reported to our developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1687

Answer (score 0):

Just don't specify any Y axis bounds.  They will be computed automatically by default.

Comment: This will add negative values on the yAxis. And they don't need.